# auditing the user logging information in oracle using trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created the following trigger, but I would need to get the username and the dml operation he performed that has logged into application instead of the user that is currently logged in the DB

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_delete
AFTER update or delete
ON orders

FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

SELECT user INTO v_username
FROM dual;

INSERT INTO orders_audit
VALUES
( :old.order_id,
:old.quantity,
:old.cost_per_item,
:old.total_cost,
sysdate,
v_username,
:new.total_cost );

END;
```

With this questy, I get the username of the user logged in the DB. I would like to have the user logged in my user application instead.

Answer (score 1):

To audit users, use the proper Oracle audit feature:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000

Much better than triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `INSERT` statement, put a check on the username using an `IF-ELSE` construct. One way to differentiate `application user` from a `schema owner` is to validate the `roles` granted to the user.

You can query the `username`, `process`, `program` from `v$session` to check whether the user is logged in through application.